# Specify globals and locals in Python Docker sdk

Tags: python-docker

This is an educational question.

I've read multiple times that python's `eval` has multiple security threats and that it should be avoided as much as possible. Then I opted for a containerized execution using docker sdk.

Here's a simplified, dummy snippet to illustrate my approach

```py
import docker

# Define the generated code as a string
generated_code = """
result = int(n) ** int(p)
print(result)
"""

# Define the values for the variables n and p
n = 2
p = 3

# Create a Docker client
client = docker.from_env()

# Define a Docker image to use as the execution environment
image_name = "python:latest"

# Create a container and run the generated code within it
container = client.containers.run(
    image=image_name,
    command=["python", "-c", generated_code],
    # environment={"n": str(n), "p": str(p)}, # <-- this does not work :(
    detach=False,
)

# Print the container's output
print(container.decode())
```

Since I have no control over the code, I would like to specify an `environment` (meaning both libs and variables) the way I would with `eval` when calling it like this: `eval(code, environment)`. Is there a way to do this with docker sdk ?

EDIT: Is preparing an image with the required environment and uploading it to dockerhub the only solution to this ?